# How to detect unused drawables in Android Studio 2021.1.1 Patch 1?

Tags: android-studio, lint

How one may detect drawables in Android projects, which are not used anywhere, using Adroid Studio 2021.1.1 Patch 1?

It is not a duplicate of [android - automatically detect unused drawables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938709/android-automatically-detect-unused-drawables) as (1) its accepted answer is not working anymore (2) it is about Eclipse, not Android Studio